# Function Pointer declaration and function definition together

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

I saw some piece of code in one of the old files.

```
void (*const m_exec[N_EXECS])(void) =
   {
       #define PROCESS_DEF_TIMED(name) name,   // defines macro for use in proclist.h
       #define PROCESS_TIMED                   // define switch for section in proclist.h
       #include "proclist.h"
       #undef PROCESS_TIMED                    // undefine switch
       #undef PROCESS_DEF_TIMED                // undefines macro
   };
```

I am unable to understand the meaning of this code. Is this a function pointer with declaration and function definition together? But if I try to declare similar function pointer like below, I get compilation error

```
void (*voidFptr)(void) =
{
    printf("Hello\n");
}
```

Also what is #define here? Why this is inside the function I am not sure.

Comment: It is populating the array of function pointers from a list contained in the `"proclist.h"`.

Comment: Run the file through the preprocessor and look at the preprocessed output.

Comment: Did you have a look at the header file? Maybe you also notice the syntax of the original is different from your's. In program code, every single character is important, often even in comments and string-literals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
void (*const m_exec[N_EXECS])(void)
```

is the way you declare an array of function pointers in C. You are not alone in finding this difficult to read. It declares an array of length `N_EXECS`, where each element in the array is a function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to a const-void.

The braces-enclosed block after it is the array initializer; probably `proclist.h` has a whole list of function pointer declarations in it, and this is essentially pasting those into this array. If you want to see what's actually happening after the `#include`, you can use the `-E` flag of your compiler. So if this were in `main.c`, you would run:

```
gcc -E -Ipath/to/headers -Iother/path/to/headers main.c
```

And it would give you a (probably huge) dump of source code, which is the result of pushing that file through the preprocessor and evaluating all of the `#include` statements.

Edit: missed your last question.

Probably (and this is conjecture without seeing `proclist.h`), the things its defining change the contents of `proclist.h`. For example, if it contained:

```
#ifdef PROCESS_TIMED
&function1_timed,
&function2_timed
#else
&function1,
&function2
#endif
```

Then `#define PROCESS_TIMED` would change what ended up in your `m_exec` array.

Comment: Can we declare a function pointer and define function together something like    'void (*voidFptr)(void) =
{
    printf("Hello\n");
}'

Comment: By defining a function, you are essentially "declaring a function pointer"; if you have `void voidf(void) { printf("Hello\n"); }`, then `voidf` and `&voidf` are equivalent and valid function pointers.